# How to force default values in an insert with EntityFramework core?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-core

When adding a record with EntityFramework Core, if I want to force a column wich has a default value to annother value, the default value is taken.

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE MyEntity(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    MyProperty1 VARCHAR(50),
    MyBool BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
```

**.NET**

```
public void insertNewMyEntity()
{
    MyEntity me = New MyEntity();
    me.MyProperty1 = "Testing insert and default values with EF Core";
    me.MyBool = 0;
    dbContext.MyEntity.Add(me);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

In the Database, there's MyBool = 1 because EntityFramework send the following command :

```
INSERT INTO MyEntity(MyProperty1) VALUES ("Testing insert and default values with EF Core");
```

Instead of :

```
INSERT INTO MyEntity(MyProperty1, MyBool) VALUES ("Testing insert and default values with EF Core", 0);
```

I could add data annotation `[DataGenerated(DataGeneratedOption.None)]` on `MyBool` but I don't want to redo all the data annotations in all entities after each classes generation with EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add data annotation `[DataGenerated(DataGeneratedOption.None)]` on the properties with the configBuilder object :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(a => a.MyBool).ValueGeneratedNever();
```